# Image not stored in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ipad

i am trying to store image in NsMutable Array.But it not working in that function. But eventually in other function it work properly.can someone tell me why it is not working.

```
- (void)readPlistData {

objectButtonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   \\Use to store Buttons
editButtonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];      \\ another array use to store deletebutton(such as.crossmark button.)
selectImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.myPlistPath = [NSString stringWithString:[self plistPath]];

plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.myPlistPath];

for (int i =0; i< [plistArray count];i++)
{


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = [plistArray objectAtIndex:i];
    currentObjectImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] ; 
    [selectImage addObject:currentObjectImage]; \\value not stored in selectimage NSMutableArray

    CGRect imageSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 90);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize.size); // this will crop

    [currentObjectImage drawInRect:imageSize];

    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, 0, 100, 90)];
    [imageButton setTag:tag];
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGRect backFrame = backView.frame;
    backFrame.size.width = 120+width;
    backView.frame = backFrame;

    [backView addSubview:imageButton];

    editButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width-10, -10, 35, 35)];
    [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    editButton.hidden = YES;
    [editButton setTag:tag];
    [backView addSubview:editButton];
    tag++;
    width = 120 + width;

    [objectButtonArray addObject:imageButton];
    [editButtonArray addObject:editButton];

}

scrollView.contentSize = backView.bounds.size;
```

}

can someone help me.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘not working’? Is it a compiler error? A runtime error? The plist is not being loaded? The images are created wrongly? There are no images at all? The buttons do not show up on the view? Please be more specific — pasting some code and saying ‘not working’ is bad form. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is Reference name "currentObjectImage" basically when you are doing

```
[selectImage addObject:currentObjectImage];
```

it saves the reference of "currentObjectImage", where in the next iteration next image is loaded in it which creates problem.

Replace above line with

```
[selectImage addObject:[currentObjectImage copy]];
```

I think it will solve your problem.